# How to initialize UITableViewController inside a UISplitViewController?

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

I just dragged out a `UISplitView` from the storyboard and set the classes of the root and detail view controllers. I am wondering how to initialize my `UITableViewController` (as it needs some setup before it is read to be used). This might be easier if I create the `UISplitView` programmatically. Still, is there a way for me to set up my `UITableViewController` in the `UISplitView`? Thanks!

Comment: Do you use storyboard ?

Comment: Yeah. I find building apps with drag and drop easy but there seems be a lot of difficulties such as this initialization problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just drag and drop a UISplitView to your storyboard and create master view and detail view classes in your bundle. Then assign each class to each viewcontrollers in xib :

[image]

Comment: Yes, I did that. The problem now is I need to initialize my master view controller class. I got an exception about some properties in the master view controller class not set up.

Comment: So inside the inspector for the `tableViewController` which is the master view controller in this case, I select my own class `MyMasterViewController` (This class was created from some external library. I extended it.). Then I ran my code, there was an exception about missing fields in this class not set up. I can correct this by calling an initializing method `MyMasterViewController *mvc = [[MyMasterViewController alloc] initWithClass: @"Order"]`.

Comment: I can also do all these programmatically. (Inside `appdelegate.m`, create instances for both master and detail view controllers and add them into a split view controller.) If I do this, I have http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21421811/difference-between-dragging-uiviews-into-storyboard-and-creating-them-programmat/21422379?noredirect=1#comment32320707_21422379 this problem