# Difference between dragging UIViews into storyboard and creating them programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

Hi I am new to iOS programming and am wondering what is the difference between dragging a `UIView` into the storyboard and create them programmatically. 
I am using an iPad for development. I have a `UISplitView`. Inside the `Appdelegate.m`, I created a `UISplitViewController` programmatically:

```
    MyTableViewController* orders = [[MyTableViewController alloc] initWithClassName:@"Order"];
    MyDetailsViewController* details = [[MyDetailsViewController alloc] init];
    UISplitViewController* splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
    splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: orders, details, nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = splitViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Inside the storyboard, I have the root view controller's class set to `MyTableViewController` and the detail view controller's class to `MyDetailsViewController`. However, if I drag another `UILabel` into the storyboard of `MyDetailsViewController` and wire it as a property of the class. It does not show up. I can only create it programmatically inside `viewDidLoad()`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //self.testLabel was dragged into the storyboard and added as a property of the class
    [self.testLabel setText:@"TESTING!"]; 
    [self.view addSubview:self.testLabel];
    // creating programmatically
    UILabel *program = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100)];
    program.text = @"im a string";
    program.hidden = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:program];
    // The second one program shows up
}
```

Why is this the case here?

Answer (score 1):

- Whenever you do a drag & drop in the story board, it actually creates a XML based file that holds every detail about the component. So there is no (objective -C) code generated. You can right click the storyboard & open it as source code to see the XML file. Any design in story board can be viewed even before the program is compiled or running.
- When you write the code, your view / view controller can be viewed only by compiling & then running the build in simulator.

Kindly right click storyboard & open it as source code, you can see how it is represented in XML tags.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I see. But I thought by connecting these `UIView`s into code (ctrl + drag) as properties, I can modify them in code as well. How come that does not work in this case?

Comment: I find drag and drop using storyboard easier for me (compared to programmatically creating `UIView`s with `CGRect`etc) to organize the views as I want. However, I do not want to lose control of them. What is your suggestion on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can write an IBOutlet in .h file of your MyDetailsViewController

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
```

Then go to storyboard and right click on your UILabel. You can see New Referencing Outlet there. Drag it to your view controller. There you will get myLabel in options. Select it. Then you can access that UILabel in your Storyboard in coding. Thus you can reduce the code and also customise UILabel properties in XIB itself avoiding coding.

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I did but it did not work (the one created by drag & drop did not show up at all). So I posted this question.

Comment: That `UILabel` created by drag and drop shows up in storyboard but not in my iPad when I run it. But the one created programmatically shows up.

Comment: It must be the problem with you autoallignment. Please check whether it aligned correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by alignment? My xCode shows the same picture above. I have no idea why it is not working. I think it might be because I create an instance of `MyDetailViewController` in `appdelegate.m` and add it to the `UISplitViewController`

Comment: Change that code to         
MyDetailsViewController* details = [[MyDetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyDetailsViewController" bundle:nil];
You are not loading the xib file.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you very much! Still wondering why that is the case though. When I create an instance of the class. Why did it appear differently like the one shown in storyboard?

Comment: Then you initialise with MyDetailsViewController* details = [[MyDetailsViewController alloc] init] it only create an instance of MyDetailsViewController class. If you need to load bib file along with that instance you have to load that xib file.